# How do you Install the Latest Release of Miro?

Tags: 12.10, miro

In the software centre the latest release of Miro available is 4.0.4 whereas the latest release of Miro is 5.0.4.

*How do I download 5.0.4 on **12.10**?*

I have tried following the guide at http://www.getmiro.com/download/for-ubuntu/ (and thus have already run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pcf/miro-releases`) but it failed and when I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` I received the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: its all written in the link given by u. 1st do this in terminal - 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pcf/miro-releases`

Then open **SYNAPTIC PACKAGE MANAGER**. If u have not installed it install it from **UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER**.

Open it press **RELOAD** and then search for miro. It will show the version 5.0.4-1 version. Then mark this and install.

If update is not shown then remove the 1st one from software center and then install the new one!

Comment: That repository doesn't exist whenever I add it and run sudo apt-get update I receive the error detailed in my question.

Comment: The repository doesn't have a version for 12.10 (Quantal). Check http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/ to see the  versions available

Comment: i didnot notice that u said 12.10. @jorgehsrama is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the source definition of the PPA from `quantal` to `precise`. For some reason Precise has the right version under packages and Quantal does not. This will definitely work for you.

Comment: glad to hear it worked out for you! It was driving me nuts personally until I dug deeper and then felt silly that it was such a simple issue. If anyone needs any personal help on how to perform this just shoot me a msg i can give you a breakdown. Miro seems to be the only podcast player that reliably keeps track of resume capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

As an update, note that the repository here:

ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists

now seems to include Miro for Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal.  However, the latest version in the repository is 4.0.4 whereas I understand that Miro version 5.0.4-1 is available for earlier versions of Ubuntu (12.04).  Not sure why this is the case.

Thanks.