# Install miro video player via terminal

Tags: video-player, miro

I’ve tried following the [instructions](http://www.getmiro.com/download/for-ubuntu/) but after installing ppa, I don't know what should I do with about the Synaptic Package Manager and all. Also my download doesn’t start automatically and when I click on 'if download doesn’t start automatically' link it takes me back to the homepage. I have no idea what I'm doing and what I've to do now? I want to **install miro via terminal!**
I’m using 14.04-LTS.
**Edits:**
I've referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228557/how-do-you-install-the-latest-release-of-miro) and successfully installed a **4.04 versioned miro**. The [homepage](http://www.getmiro.com/) shows the latest version as **6.0** What should I do to upgrade?

Comment: It looks like the package is pretty old. What version of Ubuntu are you running? (Output of `cat /etc/*release` will tell you.)

Comment: Reload your page @KGIII Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Ah ha! You speedy devil. Will a .deb do? It should install via GDebi just fine. I see a version for the current release but you need to go with your release version's name. Or want to try it, at any rate. See [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/miro).

Comment: I will have to install Gdebi first ryt? Then download the version from the link you provided and open it with gdebi and done? @KGIII

Comment: GDebi should already be installed - I think it's default with every Ubuntu but, if not, go ahead and install it. There's an "apt" link at the URL I gave you but I've never tried it.

Comment: It installed a 4.0.4 version and I wanted the 6.0.1 version.. What should I do? @KGIII and others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31597/discussion-between-abhishah901-and-kgiii).

Comment: Do you want to install `miro` or you want to install only from that particular PPA? @abhishah901

Comment: Please read the edits @Ravan

Comment: yes I saw, please see my answer @abhishah901

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: I asked specifically using **the terminal** @Braiam

Comment: You don't need a terminal to 1) adding a ppa 2) install software. You need miro, that question will help you get miro, if you get the correct ppa. Oh, and project seems dead since 2013, so don't expect it to work *out of the box*.

Comment: You get the 4.0 version at the software centre but I want the latest!@Braiam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and run (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Note: These are third party PPA's for miro and ffmpeg, **not supported by their developers**, they may be obsolete and insecure (at the moment of this post, the latest build of FFmpeg was 2014-03-29 which lags behind [several Security Advisories](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3611/Ffmpeg.html) and Miro 2014-10-22), [use it at you own risk.](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/169736)

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ppa
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joyard-nicolas/ffmpeg
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ffmpeg miro
```

<sub>reference [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/install-miro-6-in-ubuntu-14-04-via-ppa/)</sub>

Comment: **Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:djcj/vlc-stable'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.** For the second command

Comment: @abhishah901 updated =)

Answer (score 2):

If `sudo apt-get install miro` does not work from the terminal then the simplest way to do this is to download the appropriate DEB file from [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/miro) site and use the appropriate version for your version of Ubuntu.

When downloaded, just open the DEB file and click on the install button. In my case, it gave a warning about there already being a copy in the repository but I just ignored it and installed with GDebi. GDebi should already be installed. If not, you can install it from the terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

This is a picture of it working with the installer still open:

[image]

Comment: Which one's the appropriate package for 14.04?

Comment: It is "Trusty" for 14.04. I don't have a 14.04 image to check but you can *probably* install the .deb file for version 6 at that site that I linked to. Otherwise, see the answer from @Ravan for more information.

Comment: Thanks but the other answer did the job **through the terminal**. Thanks for the help though! Appreciated!

Comment: Perfect. Glad you got it sorted. I'll leave it up in case someone decides to do it with the GUI. I'm on 15.10 so it is already in the repository which would have been cheating. :D