# how to install the latest of miro via terminal?

Tags: miro

How to install the latest of miro via terminal?
I've tried
[How do you Install the Latest Release of Miro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228557/how-do-you-install-the-latest-release-of-miro)
but that doesn't work on my system.
I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
Thanks, Igor

Comment: Did you look in https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to see if the package is available?

Comment: The app has not been updated since 12.10, almost 7 years ago https://launchpad.net/~pcf/+archive/ubuntu/miro-releases  Even the key file is invalid for 18.04 so there is probably no way to install the app.

Comment: The source <https://tecadmin.net/install-miro-player-on-ubuntu/> recommended <sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pcf/miro-releases> and that failed. A lot of "E."  I tried to copy and paste here what the terminal wrote but that failed here. "Too long."

Comment: Thanks. Got it. And I tried packages.ubuntu.com -- no "miro" there. Does it mean we haven't any backup for vlc?

Comment: You can always [download the source](https://github.com/pculture/miro) and start maintaining it yourself...

Comment: Thank you, Fabby. Tried & failed. Maybe, because something is wrong with my updates. I posted that.